# Access clipboard from Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible for the browser to access clipboard when user presss `CTRL` + `V`? Using pure Javascript approach.

The idea being, I have a web application that needs to be able to access the clipboard when user press the key combination.

Comment: You could probably focus a hidden input when the user press ctrl.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate the other questions are "Copy to" where mine is "Copy from" clipboard